# Unable to push Vue Project to Github

Tags: git, github

For some reason `git push -u origin master` only pushed the `README.md` file of my `Vue` Project. I have built the project and it is impossible to push. What do you think is going on? It says that everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the files are not `added/commited`.

Check the files which you want to add/commit by using `git status`
It will show you the list of files which are not commited.

Try the following steps if you find any files after running `git status`

```
git add .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push origin master
```

it will add and push all files to the master